# Adding Mouse Up Command to numericUpDown wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to add an additional feature to my custom control spinner but I get an error when I attempt to add another command. Anyone who has experience with this, could you possibly explain why this continues to error out. You can find the line in question by just searching for 'MouseUp' which is near the lower 3rd of the XAML. When i attempt to add it, it crashes.

The error:

> Exception thrown: 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' in
>   PresentationFramework.dll

**Numeric.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:btl="clr-namespace:NumericSpinner"
                    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
                    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/NumericSpinner;component/Resources/AllBrushes.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type btl:NumericSpinnerControl}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type btl:NumericSpinnerControl}">

                    <Grid Background="{Binding Path=Background, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" >
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <!--
                            we use the TemplatedParent binding to get a reference to the control
                            this template has been applied to, so we can access the property on it
                        -->
                        <TextBox Grid.Row="0"
                                 Grid.Column="0"
                                 Width="Auto"
                                 Margin="0,0,1,0"
                                 VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                 BorderThickness="0"
                                 BorderBrush="Transparent"
                                 IsReadOnly="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},
                                                      Path=IsReadOnly, 
                                                      Mode=TwoWay}"

                                 Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},
                                                Path=FormattedValue,
                                                Mode=TwoWay,
                                                NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True,
                                                NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True,
                                                UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus,
                                                NotifyOnValidationError=True}" 
                                 btl:TextBoxBehavior.SelectAllTextOnFocus ="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},
                                                                                     Path=SelectAllOnGotFocus,
                                                                                     Mode=TwoWay}"
                                 >

                            </TextBox>
                        <Grid x:Name="grid1"
                              Grid.Column="1"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                              VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RepeatButton Grid.Row="0"
                                          Grid.Column="1"
                                          Width="22"
                                          Height="11"
                                          Background="Transparent"
                                          IsEnabled="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},
                                                              Path=CanIncrement}"
                                          Command="{x:Static btl:NumericSpinnerControl.IncreaseCommand}"
                                          MouseUp="{x:Static btl:NumericSpinnerControl.MouseUpCommand}">
                                <RepeatButton.Content>
                                    <Rectangle Width="16"
                                               Height="5"
                                               Fill="{StaticResource BrushScrollUp}" />
                                </RepeatButton.Content>
                                <RepeatButton.InputBindings>
                                    <MouseBinding MouseAction="RightClick" Command="{x:Static btl:NumericSpinnerControl.SetValueToMaximumCommand}"/>
                                </RepeatButton.InputBindings>
                            </RepeatButton>
                            <RepeatButton Grid.Row="1"
                                          Grid.Column="1"
                                          Width="22"
                                          Height="11"
                                          Background="Transparent"
                                          IsEnabled="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},
                                                              Path=CanDecrement}"
                                          Command="{x:Static btl:NumericSpinnerControl.DecreaseCommand}">
                                <RepeatButton.Content>
                                    <Rectangle Width="16"
                                               Height="5"
                                               Fill="{StaticResource BrushScrollDown}" />
                                </RepeatButton.Content>
                                <RepeatButton.InputBindings>
                                    <MouseBinding MouseAction="RightClick" Command="{x:Static btl:NumericSpinnerControl.SetValueToMinimumCommand}"/>
                                </RepeatButton.InputBindings>
                            </RepeatButton>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <!--  Resource dictionary entries should be defined here.  -->
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**The commands being called are these:**

```
public static RoutedCommand IncreaseCommand { get; set; }

protected static void OnIncreaseCommand(Object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    NumericSpinnerControl control = sender as NumericSpinnerControl;

    if (control != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Pressed");
        control.OnIncrease();
    }
}

protected void OnIncrease()
{
    Value = LimitValueByBounds(Value + Increment, this);
}

public static RoutedCommand MouseUpCommand { get; set; }

protected static void OnMouseUpCommand(Object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    NumericSpinnerControl control = sender as NumericSpinnerControl;

    if (control != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("mouse up");
    }
}

private static void InitializeCommands()
{
    //  create instances
    IncreaseCommand = new RoutedCommand("IncreaseCommand", typeof(NumericSpinnerControl));
    MouseUpCommand = new RoutedCommand("MouseUpCommand", typeof(NumericSpinnerControl));

    //  register the command bindings - if the buttons get clicked, call these methods.
    CommandManager.RegisterClassCommandBinding(typeof(NumericSpinnerControl), new CommandBinding(IncreaseCommand, OnIncreaseCommand));
    CommandManager.RegisterClassCommandBinding(typeof(NumericSpinnerControl), new CommandBinding(MouseUpCommand, OnMouseUpCommand));
}
```

Comment: Well, for one thing, your XAML is missing `</RepeatButton.InputBindings>` AND `</RepeatButton>`.

Comment: i know that. i just focused on the specific part where the problem occurs

Comment: Your posted XAML should be accurate, specially because you're getting a `XamlParseException`.

Comment: understandable. I can post a larger section of the xaml

Comment: No, post at least the missing closing tags.

Comment: a) what is 'Command' , and b) 'MouseUp' property in your starting tag <RepeatButton ...>